# Is it possible to direct phone audio output to PC input using mic

Tags: windows, audio, sound-editing

Is it possible to redirect phone or other electronic device audio (not from speaker) to PC and record it on PC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just get the appropriate cable.

Do note, most pc's and soundcards do have a microphone AND Line-in connector. The difference is that the microphone input is both mono and amplified.

This will cause the audio quality to be poor and the sound will quickly distort. Use the line-in input instead for good quality.

Comment: Is it like just to connect the phone output to pc mic using an AUX cable and choose line-in as input and done?

Comment: It depends on your computer. Some soundcards have a shared mic and line-in, and in these cases you have to tell your soundcard that it is a line-in port. In other cases they are two separate connectors and you just connect them with a male-male 25mm jack cable.

Comment: Normally blue connector is Line in, while pink one is Mic